# Fetching all the values in a MySQL column and outputting it as csv text in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I have been looking all over Stack Overflow and the PHP documentation for an answer to this. So far every time I have tried the example I have gotten a server error or the query failed. This PHP file should be able to perform two functions:

1. Print out CSV formatted data from all the data in the column called DeviceName in the table with a name of the $tourcode.
2. Do the same, but with the table StoredTours and the column StoredTourName.

Once the CSV formatted output is printed, I will then use it in a spinner or list picker for the app.

[Picture of Database with the name 801929](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2gAUo.png)

Here is the Code I have so far with the $action value in the URL being the variable to control what the file does.

```
<?php

$DBUSER = 'clientapp'; 
$DBPW ='///PASSWORD///';
//$DBPW = $_GET['passwd'];
$DBHOST = 'localhost'; 
$DBNAME = '///DBNAME///'; 

$dbc = mysqli_connect($DBHOST,$DBUSER,$DBPW,$DBNAME);
if (!$dbc) {
    die("Database connection failed: " . mysqli_error($dbc));
exit();
}

//$tourcode = $_GET['tourcode'];
//$action = $_GET['action'];

$tourcode = '801929';
$action = 'devices';

if ($action === 'devices') {

    /* Here I want to print all the values in the column called 
    DeviceName form the table whose name is = $tourcode */


} else if ($action === 'tours') {

    /* Do the same as above, but with the table being 
    StoredTours and the column called StoredTourName */


}?>
```

It would be very helpful if someone could help me do this.

Comment: so what errors were you getting?

Comment: All the code examples I tried to put in the areas that are now commented out I would get a standard SQL Query error or the web browser error code 500.